# Unity: issue with joystick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-container

For the third day I'm suffering with the control for a mobile game. I want to implement control via the joystick.

I want such control in the game as in Color Road - https://vk.com/video174341022_456239047
And I did this here (via joystick) - https://vk.com/video174341022_456239048

The difference is that in the game Color Road hamburger can be kept in the center without any strain, it is very convenient from the edge of the screen to go to the center. In my control to keep in the center of the screen you need to make a lot of effort, because if you push the joystick slightly more to the left, the triangle flies to the edge of the screen, and if you do not let the joystick go to the left, it will move at the speed of the turtle.

**My joystick code:**

```
public class VirtualJoystick : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler {

    private Image backgroundImage;
    private Image joystickImage;
    private Vector3 inputVector;

    private void Start()
    {
        backgroundImage = GetComponent<Image>();
        joystickImage = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
    }

    public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector2 pos;
        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(backgroundImage.rectTransform, eventData.position,
            eventData.pressEventCamera, out pos))
        {
            pos.x = (pos.x / (backgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x));
            //pos.y = (pos.y / backgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

            inputVector = new Vector3(pos.x * 2f, 0, 0);
            inputVector = (inputVector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? inputVector.normalized : inputVector;

            joystickImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(inputVector.x * (backgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 2),
                inputVector.z * inputVector.y);
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        OnDrag(eventData);
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        inputVector = Vector3.zero;
        joystickImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
    }

    public float Horizontal()
    {
        if (inputVector.x != 0)
        {
            return inputVector.x;
        }
        else
        {
            return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        }
    }
}
```

**Control triangle:**

```
public class PlayerMover : MonoBehaviour {

    public VirtualJoystick joystick;
    private Vector3 MoveVector;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    public float moveSpeed = 10;

    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        MoveVector = PoolInput();
        Move();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        rigidbody.velocity = ((MoveVector * moveSpeed));
    }

    private Vector3 PoolInput()
    {
        Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;

        dir.x = joystick.Horizontal();
        dir.y = 0;
        dir.z = 0;
        if (dir.magnitude > 1)
            dir.Normalize();
        Debug.Log("Dir = " + dir);
        return dir;
    }

}
```

I can not find any info to fix this. Everywhere the same tutorials. Maybe it's something else you need to implement? Not through the joystick? What is the problem with such a wooden control for me?
P.S Sorry for my bad english